# Android Studio: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am making a blank installation of Android Studio, then I make a new Android app. After trying to debug I get "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

Now I am searching for hours for a solution, but changing the cacerts file is not working for me.

app/ build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.da_ma.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Application build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Anyone ideas?

Comment: I faced similar issue with gradle and it was something with our office firewall policy.  It started working when we white listed the url the gradle was calling.

Comment: Ah ok, so when I try this in another network it should work. I will test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing all https to http in build.gradle worked for me.
ex : -

```
   maven {
        url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
```

To : -

```
 maven {
        url "http://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
    }
```

Hope it work for others too.